# TFS DLM: Should Database and Application be separate Build definitions?

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, release-management

I am trying to setup an application and database in TFS 2017.  For a standard windows application and SQL Database Project.

Should I combine the application project and the SQL Database Project into the same solution and Build together on TFS in the same Build Definition?

I a thinking these should be separate solutions in TFS and separate Build definitions in TFS.  We can include multiple artifact references in TFS Release to deploy them both simultaneously.

Does this make sense?

Or does it make more sense to combine the solution and build definition into the same units of work?

Comment: Just start with the single solution as it is easier to maintain at the beginning. After that it is very easy to move it to the separate solution.

Answer (score 1):

Few questions to ask yourself:

1. Do the database changes need to go out with the code changes?
   Probably combine them
2. Is the DB something maintained by another group that you just keep in sync? Maybe split them up
3. Is the database build adding a lot of time to your CI? Maybe split them up to improve performance, or cache the DacPac between builds
4. If they are in separate solutions, how are you planning to do code reviews or branching?

I've usually combined them, but have been thinking about something closer to the 3rd question to speed up builds.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is a structure for organizing projects in Visual Studio. Whether combine the application project and the SQL Database Project into the same solution depends on your projects structure.

On TFS side, it's OK to use one build definition, as if you want to build only one project, you can specify the particular project.